# Найти минимальное расстояние между точками

Tags: python, python-3.x, алгоритм, графы, networkx

Нам нужно перейти из одной точки на плоскости в другую.
Но у нас есть ограничение на расстояние перехода за 1 раз

Также у нас даны координаты еще нескольких точек
Например:

```
1 1    
6 6    
2 3    
6 7    
3 9
```

Если сразу напрямую перейти нельзя(из-за огран), то придется переходить через другие точки.Как найти минимальное расстояние?

Comment: Первое что приходит на ум это построить граф, отбросив все рёбра не удовлетворяющие ограничению. Веса рёбер - расстояния. Дальше ищем кратчайший путь.

Comment: С помощью чего в питоне это лучше реализовать ?

Comment: Я бы копал в сторону “networkx” и “scipy” / “sklearn”

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Идея:** строим граф, отбросив все рёбра не удовлетворяющие ограничению. Веса рёбер - расстояния. Дальше ищем кратчайший путь.

**Реализация** с использованием модулей: Pandas, SciPy, NetworkX:

```
import pandas as pd
import networkx as nx
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist, pdist, squareform
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# maximum allowed distance
max_dist = 5

# reading points coordinates CSV -> Pandas.DataFrame
df = pd.read_csv(r'c:/temp/data.csv', header=None, names=['x','y'])

# adjacency matrix of distances
adj_mx = squareform(pdist(df))
adj_mx[adj_mx > max_dist] = 0

# building a graph from the adjacency matrix
G = nx.from_numpy_matrix(adj_mx)

source = 0  # index of the source point
target = 3  # index of the target point

path = nx.shortest_path(G, source=source, target=target, weight='weight')
print(f'the shortest path between [{source}] and [{target}]: {path}')


#### drawing the graph
# node's positions
pos = nx.spring_layout(G)
edge_labels = {k:f'{v:.3}' for k,v in nx.get_edge_attributes(G, 'weight').items()}

nx.draw_networkx(G, pos, node_size=700)
nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(G, pos, edge_labels=edge_labels)

plt.show()
```

**Вывод на печать:**

```
the shortest path between [0] and [3]: [0, 2, 1, 3]
```

**График:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: Не пропускает либу networkx, придется мне как-то это в ручную делать)

Comment: я пользуюсь дистрибутивом Anaconda - в нем установка: `conda install networkx`. Да и обычный `pip install networkx` должен нормально утсанавливать NetworkX

Comment: Я про компилятор сайта,на котором весит эта задача,он для решения задачи не все либы пропускает

Answer (score 1):

Возможно вам поможет [волновой алгоритм](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D0%9B%D0%B8).

- посетите все возможные точки от начальной, отметьте их как "шаг 1"

- посетите все непосещенные точки, доступные из точек "шаг 1" и отметьте их как "шаг 2"

- повторяйте шаги, пока не посетите нужную вам точку

- когда дойдете до нужной точки - восстановите путь назад до исходной находя ближайшую точку предыдущего шага

Comment: Эта "разновидность" - BFS, поиск в ширину, на самом деле - основа волнового и др. Однако тут не показано, как учитывать веса рёбер (расстояния)

Comment: Я предполагаю, что если по пути назад выбирать ближайшую точку - то все должно получиться. Надо проверить.

Answer (score 0):

1. Построить граф связности точек с учетом ограничений по переходам.
2. Использовать А*